# Rebuild a JPEG image from backup data

Tags: xml, jpeg

A friend of mine used a software on his cellphone to backup messages but now this software does no longer exist (I don't even know the name). The backup he has is a XML file with a lot of data that I had no problem to sort and recover, but the pictures are stored with the following format :

```
<part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="2015-08-11_17.45.15.jpg" chset="null" cd="null" fn="null" 
cid="&lt;2015-08-11_17.45.jpg&gt;" cl="2015-08-11_17.45.15.jpg" ctt_s="null" ctt_t="null"
 text="null" data="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAICAgICAQICAgIDAg [..A lot of data encoded here..] obmqpJ
H//Z" />
```

And I have no idea how to rebuild a picture from this. Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

This is [`base64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding, you can use various tools to decode this plain text back to original blob.

```
$ base64 -d <<< /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAICAgICAQICAgIDAg |  hexdump -C
00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  |......JFIF......|
00000010  00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43  00 02 02 02 02 02 01 02  |.......C........|
00000020  02 02 02 03 02                                    |.....|
```

`ff d8` is a valid JPEG header, which verified with the data in `cid` and `ct`.

Comment: Oh really ! 
Thank you, it should solve everything :)